# C programming. Function to generate a string of random letters using only arrays and then pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Im trying to code a program in C to generate a string containing random letters using only arrays first and then again using pointers. I've looked at many other questions but is not quite what I'm trying to accomplish. I can really use help please.

- Function 1- Generates a string with random upper 
  case letter A-Z with 40 characters.
- Function 2- Function to let user enter a string
  with random upper case letter and a replacement character.
- Function 3- Searches string1 from function 1 and replaces
  occurences of any character from string 2 (user entered) with 
  replacement character.

**OUTPUT EX.**

```
String 1- "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHABCDEFGH"

String 2- "BE"

Replacement char- "3"

Filtered string- AA33CCDD33FFGGHHA3CD3FGH.
```

This is what I have so far, Im not very good with arrays.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()

{

int s1 [41];

    srand(time(NULL));  
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 41; i++)

     {

    s1 [i] = rand();

    }

return 0;

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
     Thanks alot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) We'll help you fix an honest attempt at solving the problem, but we won't write the code for you.

Comment: Are you willing to use rand() function? e.g. Use a library function that generates a random number?

If you want to make the randomization by yourself, your question should be totally different. The question should be: How do I generate a random number with no external libraries with C?

Comment: ***Show Code*** What exactly do you need help with?  You've given us a spec, but no code, and no question.

Comment: `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[randon_number]` - repeat this 40 times.

Comment: This is what I have so far, Im not very good with arrays.       int s1 [41] srand(time(NULL));  int i;
for (i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
    s1 [i] = rand();
}

Comment: So... you don't even have `int main(void)` yet?  Cause you're definitely going to need that.   Maybe also a `return 0;`?

Comment: Not related to your question, but something to keep in the back of your mind: rand() doesn't have the same probability of selecting every possible letter so it isn't truly random.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah A true random number does not exist (;

Comment: @4386427 Do I have to assign s1 that many times? I understand s1[41]is  null since we want the last cell to be terminated  by null since its a string

Comment: @4386427 Thank you, that helps with the start, i appreciate it

Comment: @4386427 I no longer see the example you sent me?

Comment: @user9593492 It's gone. Always remember to copy stuff in comments if you want to save it. Comments may disappear at any time and can't be recovered. Anyway, see https://ideone.com/4pV9dF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void rand_str(char* txt, size_t sz)
{
    int i=sz-1;
    while( i --> 0 )
    {
        txt[i] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
    }
    printf("Random Str: %.*s\n", sz+i, txt);
}

void fn2(char* tgt, size_t sz, char* repl )
{
    puts("String 2: ");
    fgets(tgt, sz, stdin);

    puts("Replacement Char: ");
    *repl = getchar();
}

void search_replace(char* txt, char* tgt, char repl)
{
    while(*tgt != '\0')
    {
        while ((strchr(txt, *tgt) ? (tgt[strchr(txt, *tgt)-tgt] = repl) : 0) == repl);
        tgt++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char txt[41] = {0};
    char tgt[40] = {0};
    char repl;

    rand_str(txt, sizeof(txt));
    fn2(tgt, sizeof(tgt), &repl);
    search_replace(txt, tgt, repl);
    return !printf("Filtered String: %s\n", txt);
}
```

Comment: String termination is in there. :)  `srand` is a minor detail compared to how much help he needs.

Comment: Im sorry for my lack of knowledge, Im just having a hard time with arrays and pointers. Does what I have above look right? Will it work for function 1?

Comment: @4386427 I try to be creative and sneaky with my code, but still correct.  If he tries to turn my code in as homework, he wont be able to explain it.

Comment: @abelenky My rand is sneakier :P

Comment: I do appreciate your help guys

Comment: @user9593492 Than show it!, upvote, upvote, upvote!!

Comment: @asafFisher @ abelenky @ 4386427 I want to understand the code though, I dont benefit if I dont get it. Im new to coding and would appreciate explanations along with code.

Comment: Upvote does not mean Solved... its just an appreciation thingy...
Read my explanation about `gets`

Comment: @abelenky while ( (strchr(txt, *tgt)? *strchr(txt, *tgt) = repl : NULL) == repl ); keeps getting a compiler error

Comment: @abelenky I get C2100 illegal indirection and C2106 '=':left operand must be l-value. And on char txt[41] = {};
 char tgt[40] = {}; im guessing the " " was missed withing brackets cus also had an error

Comment: You are using a strange compiler! But i made some changes that might help.

Comment: @abelenky Im using visual studios. I am still getting the same errors along with warnings 'strchr' undefined, assuming extern return unit and operand of '*' must be a pointer (these were also there before, not new after update)

Comment: I'm getting the same errors in Visual Studio, but not with other compilers.   I changed it to work in Visual Studio now. (But I'm very confident my original code was valid C)

Comment: @abelenky So im getting C2113 error. on the same line '-': pointer can only be subtracted from another pointer. So i added an asterisk on (tgt[strchr(txt, *tgt) - *tgt] and now it runs but when i enter all user entries it gives me an "exception thrown" and before i see my filtered string it just closes out and returns to source code. AH

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not getting that error on either of my compilers.  I'm not sure how else to help you.

Comment: It's ok, youve been a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I did not compile any of this code. It might have some typo and/or runtime errors. The concept is correct though and you should understand the code first and not just copy it.

Function 1:

```
    #include <stdlib.h> // Important! rand() function that generate random function is in that library!
    //This function returns a pointer of an array (arr). In other words it returns the **address** of the first character of the array.
// Assuming arr is valid!
    char* randomString(char* arr){
       // This part does not REALLLYY matters it just makes sure the random will truly be random...
        time_t t;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t)); // Seeds the random function.
       //------------------
//Looping the array assigning random letters:
        int i = 0;
        while(i<SIZE){
            arr[i] = 'A'+(rand()%('Z'-'A'+1));// 'A' has a numerical value, we want the range from 'A' to 'Z' to be random. 'Z'-'A' is the range of letters (26) because its a modulu if the modulu was just 'Z'-'A' (26) it wouldnt print Z. 'Z' is the 26th letter, 26%26 is zero, it will not give 'Z' this is why I increased 'Z'-'A' by 1 so the modulu will include 'Z' as random latter. 
            i = i + 1;
        }
        arr[i] = 0;// String terminator also called NULL.
        return "lol";
    }
```

Function 2:

```
#include <string.h>
int replace(char* inputString, char* userInput,char replacement ){
    /* e.g. 
       inputString = "ABSDSADASBBBAA";//Generate yourself... (Might want to user function 1)
       userInput = "AB"; // You need to do the user input yourself...
       replacement = 'D';
    */
    int i = 0;
    while(i<strlen(inputString)){
        int j = 0;
        while(j<strlen(userInput)){
            if(inputString[i]==userInput[j]){
                inputString[i] = replacement;
            }
            j = j+1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Function 3:

```
 int main(){
    // Just use regular IO libraries to get user's input...
    // Assuming you did that, I will hard code the values (you need to do the IO e.g. gets())
    char str[SIZE];
    randomString(str); // Requirement #1 reuse of function 1
    char * userInput = "AB"; // You need to do the user input yourself...
    char replacement = 'D';// You need to do the user input yourself...
    replace(str, userInput, replacement)//Requirement #2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this using a mix of arrays and pointers? I'm just beginning to learn pointers, how would this look like with pure arrays?

Comment: As you can see, A string is simply and array of chars. Now, there is a use of pointers here, `char* inputString` is a declaration of a  pointer (named `inputString`) that points to the beginning of the array. So inputString is a pointer. inputString's value is an address (that points to a 'cell' that contains the first letter of the array) Therefore if i will do for  example: `printf(%c,*inputString);` it will print the first character inthe array. *inputString is also equivilant to `inputString[0]`. it is acctually EXACTLY the same thing.

Comment: @4386427 Would you believe me if I told you that I wrote that with a BlackBerry phone? Fixed...

Comment: @4386427 You should try one, you'll feel 3% freeEr

Comment: @AsafFisher I understand that, * is to dereference and get the content of that cell. It's just understanding the whole thing that gets confusing. Im also supposed to use gets and puts

Comment: Use the documentation. gets (which should not be used anymore in general) get a pointer as a parameter (pointer to a char array). It does not return anything because it manipulate the array on the address you sent to it... lets say i have `char arr[255];`
now call `gets(arr);` 
gets will assign the `stdin` string into `arr` and will terminate (assign `NULL`) to the last place.
If you  `printf` arr now, it will show the input string...
(Please upvote I worked hard with my BlackBerry producing this explanations...)

Comment: `randomString` should be void or `return arr;` If void you need to fix main

Comment: @AsafFisher is upvoting simply hitting the up arrow on your answer? And how does that benefit you if i may ask, im new to all this sorry. Also all the function calling and execution has to be done through main function

Comment: Upvotes add me points, V mark, mark's my post as a solution. If you did  not find my post helpful, you dont marked as solved. If it helped you but did not answer the question in your opinion, you just upvote. If post answered your question, upvote and mark V

Comment: Read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for basic information about upvoting, accepting answers and using this site.   When presented with working code, you should be able to understand the basics from it.   We should not need to explain it line-by-line to you.